# Cannot initialise wifi_config.ap.ssid with const char * ssid

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I am trying to write a function that will take ssid, password, channel and maximum connected devices to initialise a WLAN AP. Below is my code.

```
void wifi_init_softap(const char * ssid, const char *password, uint8_t channel, uint8_t max_conn)
    {
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());                // Initialise ESP Netif, Which manages the DHCP Server
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default()); // Create new event loop
    
        // esp_netif_create_default_wifi_ap();
        esp_netif_t *p_netif = esp_netif_create_default_wifi_ap(); // Create Default Wifi AP
    
        esp_netif_ip_info_t ipInfo; // Stores IP & Gateway & Netmask
    
        // Assignes default values to ip stack
        IP4_ADDR(&ipInfo.ip, 192, 168, 1, 1);
        IP4_ADDR(&ipInfo.gw, 192, 168, 1, 1);
        IP4_ADDR(&ipInfo.netmask, 255, 255, 255, 0);
    
        // Stop DHCP Server on p_netif, assign the new IP stack, and restart it
        esp_netif_dhcps_stop(p_netif);
        esp_netif_set_ip_info(p_netif, &ipInfo);
        esp_netif_dhcps_start(p_netif);
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,
                                                            ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID,
                                                            &wifi_event_handler,
                                                            NULL,
                                                            NULL));
    
        wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    
        // uint8_t *buffer_ssid = (uint8_t *)malloc((strlen(ssid)) * sizeof(char)+1);
        // memcpy(buffer_ssid, ssid, (strlen(ssid)) * sizeof(char) );
    
    
        wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
            .ap = {
                .ssid = "*ssid",
                .ssid_len = strlen(ssid),
                .channel = channel,
                .password = "(*password)",
                .max_connection = max_conn,
                .authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK},
        };
        if (strlen(password) == 0)
        {
            wifi_config.ap.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_OPEN;
        }
    
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_AP));
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_AP, &wifi_config));
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());
    
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "wifi_init_softap finished. SSID:%s password:%s channel:%d",
                 ssid, password, max_conn);
    }
```

The issue is with the following part:

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
        .ap = {
            .ssid = "*ssid",
            .ssid_len = strlen(ssid),
            .channel = channel,
            .password = "(*password)",
            .max_connection = max_conn,
            .authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK},
    };
```

When I pass ssid and passord as string constants like above, it compiles and functions correctly. However if I try passing them as variables to initialise wifi_config.ap.ssid like below it spits out an error I cannot understand.

Code:

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
            .ap = {
                .ssid = *ssid,
                .ssid_len = strlen(ssid),
                .channel = channel,
                .password = *password,
                .max_connection = max_conn,
                .authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK},
        };
```

Error Message:

```
missing braces around initializer [-Werror=missing-braces]
```

I fail to come up with a solution to this. On "esp_wifi_types.h" the types of member variables to wifi_ap_config_t can be found as below.

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ssid[32];           /**< SSID of ESP32 soft-AP. If ssid_len field is 0, this must be a Null terminated string. Otherwise, length is set according to ssid_len. */
    uint8_t password[64];       /**< Password of ESP32 soft-AP. */
    uint8_t ssid_len;           /**< Optional length of SSID field. */
    uint8_t channel;            /**< Channel of ESP32 soft-AP */
    wifi_auth_mode_t authmode;  /**< Auth mode of ESP32 soft-AP. Do not support AUTH_WEP in soft-AP mode */
    uint8_t ssid_hidden;        /**< Broadcast SSID or not, default 0, broadcast the SSID */
    uint8_t max_connection;     /**< Max number of stations allowed to connect in, default 4, max 10 */
    uint16_t beacon_interval;   /**< Beacon interval which should be multiples of 100. Unit: TU(time unit, 1 TU = 1024 us). Range: 100 ~ 60000. Default value: 100 */
    wifi_cipher_type_t pairwise_cipher;   /**< pairwise cipher of SoftAP, group cipher will be derived using this. cipher values are valid starting from WIFI_CIPHER_TYPE_TKIP, enum values before that will be considered as invalid and default cipher suites(TKIP+CCMP) will be used. Valid cipher suites in softAP mode are WIFI_CIPHER_TYPE_TKIP, WIFI_CIPHER_TYPE_CCMP and WIFI_CIPHER_TYPE_TKIP_CCMP. */
    bool ftm_responder;         /**< Enable FTM Responder mode */
} wifi_ap_config_t;
```

Comment: With the function signature you show above, `const char * ssid` means `*ssid` is a single character. That is not a valid initializer. As `ssid` is an array in that struct, you cannot initialize from a pointer. Only from a string literal. Use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: @Gerhardh tried it This time gives the message: initialization of 'unsigned char' from 'const char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: I've updated comment as you initialize an array

Comment: Which line is the message about? Initializing `ssid` doesn't make an integer from a pointer

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks that solved the issue. You gave me a new insigth! I am updating the post with the solution.

Comment: @Gerhardh sorry, deleted it.

Comment: You shouldn't define your own types ending in `_t`; it's undefined behavior in POSIX applications that include any header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ssid` field of `wifi_config_t` is an array and your `ssid` function argument is a pointer, you cannot just assign the latter to the former. What you need is to copy the data pointed by the pointer to the array. If your SSID is a null-terminated string then you should be able to do that with the `strlcpy` function, like this:

```c
// destination first, source second, max size of buffer last
strlcpy(wifi_config.ap.ssid, ssid, 32);
```

If `strlcpy` is not available, you may need to use `strncpy` instead, although `strlcpy` should be used if available as it guarantees to null-terminate the string in the destination array. If neither is available, then you need to manually find the length of the string pointed to by `ssid` using the `strlen` function and then use `memcpy` to copy this many bytes from `ssid` to `wifi_config.ap.ssid`, similarly to how it is done with `strlcpy`:

```c
size_t ssid_length = strlen(ssid);
memcpy(wifi_config.ap.ssid, ssid, ssid_length);
```

Again, this is all assuming the string pointed to by `ssid` pointer is null-terminated. If it is not, you need some other way of finding out the length of the SSID string.

---

This is due to the fact that assignment `=` does not work with arrays. Notable exception, which you are using right now, is assignment of constant strings. If you assign a constant string to an array it will automatically be translated into a `memcpy` call by some compilers. However, it does not work with non-constant strings like your `ssid` pointer. In this case, the compiler tries to assign the value of the pointer (address of your string, which is an integer-like value) to an array of `uint8_t`. Understandably, the operation does not make sense so compiler throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Neither strlcopy nor strncopy worked for me as the compiler complained about signedness. I resorted to a bytewise copy:

```
for (k=0; k<strlen(ssid); k++)
{
    wifi_config.ap.ssid[k] = ssid[k];
}
```